# How to only create .pot files with django manage.py makemessages

Tags: django, gettext, manage.py, weblate

Weblate has an add-on called "Update PO files to match POT (msgmerge)". I want to delegate the creation of `.po` files to Weblate and only use `manage.py makemessages` to create the `.pot` file(s).

`manage.py makemessages` has a `--keep-pot` option, which adds `.pot` files to the output. Unfortunately there is no option to *only* keep the `.pot` files.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to skip the creation of `.po` files by overwriting the `write_po_file` method of the `makemessages` command. To do so, create a `makemessages.py` file in `management/commands` (as described in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/)):

```py
# management/commands/makemessages.py
class Command(makemessages.Command):

    def write_po_file(*args, **kwargs):
        """Overwrite method to do nothing.

        We do not want to interfere with Weblate's
        "Update PO files to match POT (msgmerge)" addon
        """
        pass
```